# Libeosa randomly crashes trying to read audio files, despite it reading fine the same files other times

Tags: python, librosa

So I mainly want some insight onto wheter this is something I can resolve or if this is a bug or some quirk of librosa itself.

In essence, I am building a database for a machine learning algorithm that uses audio recordings in the .flac format.

Sometimes, the program crashes, with librosa spitting out an error log saying that it couldn't find a given file.

Other times, and the critical part in this, *WITHOUT* altering the code nor the database, it loads the files fine and carries on (doesn't even throw warnings which is odd concerning the prior behaviour)

Only other thing of note is that my computer's memory is quite full, and the hardware is old (2015-2016) with my RAM being a bit of a bottleneck.

Any insight over what might be happening?

Edit:
Nevermind, I found the bug, garbage is randomly being feed to the list containing the file names.

Comment: Here's the warning it spits

`UserWarning: PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead.
  warnings.warn("PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead.")`

And the crash message:

`RuntimeError: Error opening './"address"/"file".flac': System error.`

Comment: Have you tried using stream() instead of load()?  It will buffer blocks of a large file like FLAC instead of trying to load it all in at once.

Comment: How large are these audio files? What else is running on your system at the same time? (Try using Task Manager or equivalent and monitoring resource usage.) Anyway, it sounds like you really have a general computer question rather than a programming question. Please try https://superuser.com if it becomes clear that "my RAM being a bit of a bottleneck" isn't actually the problem.